Why does -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic not include -Wsign-conversion with clang?
Consider the following program:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int64_t foo(void) {
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t x = foo();
    printf("x = %zu\n", x);

    return 0;
}

clang 15.0.0 produces a clean build with -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic, but a warning is produced when -Wsign-conversion is enabled.  I understand why I don't actually want all warnings to be enabled, but sign conversion seems like a questionable omission, especially since -Wsign-compare is enabled by -Wextra.
What is the reasoning for -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic not enabling -Wsign-conversion?

Not a clang developer, so no real inside info, but a not-so-wild guess is that it produces lots of warnings. It is well known that -1 produces the maximum value for unsigned ints.

Agree that -Wsign-conversion produces lots of warnings when coding has been soft on sign-ness changes.  Better to let careful programmers enable it intentionally rather than part of some collective warning set.

I feel like the same reasoning could be applied to -Wsign-compare, which is where my confusion is originating.  When would you ever want to warn on compare but not on conversion?

@grendell Because integer conversion between signed and unsigned values is well-defined(albeit potentially implementation well-defined).  But comparison between signed and unsigned values involves integer promotion so the types match, which is fraught with bug-creating nuances and corner cases.

@grendell because -1 > 0u

-Wconversion and everything that sorts under it was always notoriously unreliable and buggy, prone to false positives. I guess that's why it was never included in -Wall or -Wextra. And then clang just inherited that from gcc. Normally clang is happy to create bugs of their own, but in this case they are merely forced to follow gcc, which behaves like it does because of gcc bugs.

Just consider something like func(1), where we have void func (int a) { unsigned int b = a; }. The sign conversion has to whine here, even though the code is safe and well-defined.

@AndrewHenle promotion refers to automatic widening. For example -(unsigned char)1 is typically equivalent to -(int)(unsigned char)1.
(I say typically because it could be that sizeof(int) == 1 and the promoted type would be unsigned int instead).
You're talking about the usual arithmetic conversions to reach a common type in a binary expression.

@MDH The usual arithmetic conversions include floating point types.  But if either value is a floating point type, both values are converted to floating point types and the signed/unsigned issue disappears (that doesn't rule out other issues), as all floating point types are signed.  Signed/unsigned comparison issues are limited to integer types.

@AndrewHenle yes, I was commenting on your use of the term promotion which is distinct from (but used in) the usual arithmetic conversions.
